# My C file_exists Function Using stat Always Fails with errno = ENOENT

Tags: c++, file, flascc

I'm using FlasCC+Swig to call my C function in Adobe Air application.

The C function:

```
int file_exists(const char filename[]) {
    struct stat stbuf;
    if (stat(filename, &stbuf) == -1) {
        return (0);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

In my normal command line (of course, first compile a main.cpp), if I supply "/tmp/test.txt" (the file exists), the function `file_exists` returns 1, which is expected.

However, after I use FlasCC+Swig to compile this C function `file_exists`, and generate a swc library, and add this library to my Adobe Air application, and run it, it always returns 0, which is incorrect.

I checked the `errno`, it's value is `ENOENT (2)`:

> A component of path does not name an existing file or path is an empty
>   string.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stat.html

Can you give me some idea?

BTW, in my Adobe Air application:

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(path);
trace(file.exists); // returns true
```

So the Adobe Air DOES have access to the local file system.

Comment: Most likely, the process is in a jail of some kind and doesn't have access to the system's `/tmp` directory.

Comment: I suspect Adobe Air runs in a sandbox like that.

Comment: It seems the Adobe Air application DOES have access to the local file system.  What if I put my files in some specific directories? (what kind of directories should I put, so that my C function `file_exist` will be able to detect it?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and Barmar, you guys are right, see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the low level c code won't be able to see the *REAL* local file system. We need to use the Adobe Virtual File System.

```
CModule.vfs.addDirectory("/MyPath/");
CModule.vfs.addFile("/MyPath/MyFile.txt", data);
```

After we set up the above VFS, our C file reading function will be able to see the file `/MyPath/MyFile.txt`.